# Destructure an array programmatically in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I have a feeling that this is not possible, but maybe there is an obscure hack that I could learn to do the following:

```
// pseudocode
let x = ["num1", "str1"]
let y = [1337, "foo"]
let [x...] = y

// desired results => 
   num1 === 1337
   str1 === "foo"
```

In other words, initialize variables with names that come from an array. In the above, the variable "num1" would be assigned the value 1337.

The use case is: the length of x and y will always be the same; their order will always match; we cannot predict the content of either. Of course, I can simply `for` on x, and match the position to the content in y, but I'd like to see if I can be more declarative and match them programmatically.

Comment: Can you please try to be more specific as to what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What should the output *actually* be?

Comment: Updated with more details about results

Comment: If variable names are decided at runtime, how can you in any way safely refer to variable `number` later on?

Comment: the shortest one. works only in global scope: `var i = 0; for (window[x[i++]] of y);` or by mutating `x`: `for (window[x.shift()] of y);`

Comment: @deceze good point

Comment: Thanks. The classic point against variable variables in any way, shape or form.

Comment: it's ugly, but you can use the powers of evil: `eval("var ["+x+"] = y;"); console.log(num1, str1);` On the other hand, I'm also with deceze, how do you intend to use the variables if you don't know their name (beforehand).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have the output as an object like so:

```js
let x = ["number", "string"];
let y = [1337, "foo"];
const res = x.reduce((acc, curr, idx) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: y[idx] }), {});
console.log(res);
```

Or if you want a two-dimensional array:

```js
let x = ["number", "string"];
let y = [1337, "foo"];
const res = x.map((e, i) => [e, y[i]]);
console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: auto; }
```

Comment: This will not work because it create object and not variable, it will only work if you update `window` object but this is only if called from global scope. No other way unless you do some eval, but this will not use destructure same as with `window` update.

Comment: What do you mean @jcubic? I don't understand...

Comment: The question was to create variable `string` and `number` not object with properties. The only way to create variables dynamically is window object or eval.

Comment: Just checked duplicate question it seem that it's possible after all, but not like in your answer.